# mongodb shell throws [thread1] InternalError: allocation size overflow @src/mongo/shell/types.js:183:23

Tags: mongodb, shell, internal

my mongodb shell is throwing errors on really basic queries even with the limit option.

I've tried reimporting datasets to no avail.

EDIT:

Javascript v8 engine has a memory limit on the stringify function so this is causing the issue.

Can the v8 memory limit be surpassed under any conditions?

Comment: .find() is working but .toArray() always throws the same error